# Treat clicks as CTRL+clicks in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, .net-3.5

I have a multi-column ListView control set to MultiSelect and Details view.  When a user clicks on any item on the list, I want to treat it as if they CTRL+clicked on the item.  So, if they click on an item that is already selected, it will deselect it.  Or, if they select a second item, it will select it without deselecting other selected items.  This is for a kiosk-style app, where input is done via touch screen and a keyboard may or may not be available to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by handling `MouseUp` event and use `HitTest` to check which item has been clicked. Then set Selected property of the item:

```
item.Selected ^= true
```

You may also check out freeware component [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) from ComponentOwl.
It has powerful owner drawing that allows you to [display items in any state](http://www.componentowl.com/blog/2011/11/how-to-display-items-in-custom-states/).
It also allows you to customize height of items. The full version offers even more interesting features.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `ListBox` instead, in owner drawn mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode.aspx